# Repeat a Report Type Multiple Times

Tags: c#, report-viewer2012

I Have a report say a Result Card. How can I Display result cards of all students in same report viewer. Is there any way to do that? If so then How?

Comment: Use a dataset that contains all students, put your result card in the detail-row, and bind the dataset to the report. The result should be a result card for each student (=record).

Comment: I am using textboxes in report card to display marks of different subjects. Using report parameters I'm passing all the values coming from database individually to those textboxes. I don't know how to use dataset in this situation. Can you help?